# Undefined entity &nbsp XML parsing exception

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to define `non breaking space entity` in the `<!doctype />` declaration. Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ] />

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  .. ....
```

But still when i am creating an XDocument object from the above document, i am getting an exception

```
Undefined entity &nbsp.
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the combination of external and internal entities in `"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]` is unnecessary because `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd` includes `www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent` which includes `<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">` which is exactly the same as yours.

So that bit should just be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Secondly, XDocument doesn't validate to a DTD by default. However, you can `Load` from an `XmlValidatingReader` or `XmlTextReader` with the appropriate settings

<del>If possible,</del>[If it's not possible, make it possible!] it's a good idea to set the XmlReader to use a `XmlPreloadedResolver`, because there's a lot of people hitting poor ol' W3C at the URI of that DTD and the .ent files it includes, and they're totally okay with you using a local copy of it (by "totally okay" I mean they'd be really glad if everyone would stop hammering their server quite so much). As well as being good for them, it'll be much faster for you.

Answer (score 12):

You can try with this entity `&#160;` instead.