# XHTML encode Android

Tags: android, xhtml, html-encode

I need to XHTML encode some text in Android.

I had been using `Html.escapeHtml()`.

However `Html.escapeHtml("  ")` generates `" &nbsp;"`. I need it to generate `" &#160"`.

Is there an equivalent? I need like a `Xhtml.escapeXhtml()`.

Or should I just do string replacements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just realized the problem is that the document is missing the DTD. I need to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to the top of the document

and then `&nbsp;` is valid.

Similar answer here: [Undefined entity &nbsp XML parsing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267003/undefined-entity-nbsp-xml-parsing-exception/12267941#12267941)